# Exception while uploading file to FTP Server

Tags: java, ftp

What I am trying to do is to upload a simple text file to the FTP Server using java code but getting error. I am trying hard to make it work but not able to do that. Below is the code.

```
    File file = new File("testFile.txt");
    FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(file);
    PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(fo);
    ps.println("BLA");
    ps.close();`enter code here`
    fo.close();
uploadFile(file,file.getName());



public void upload( String ftpServer, String user, String password,
    String fileName, FileInputStream is ) throws MalformedURLException,
    IOException  

            {

        log("inside upload...........");
        if (ftpServer != null && fileName != null && is != null)
        {
            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer( "ftp://" );
            // check for authentication else assume its anonymous access. 
            if (user != null && password != null) 
            {
                sb.append( user );
                sb.append( ':' );
                sb.append( password ); 
                sb.append( '@' );
            }
            sb.append( ftpServer );
            sb.append( '/' );
            sb.append( fileName );
            /*
             * type ==> a=ASCII mode, i=image (binary) mode, d= file directory
             * listing
             */
            sb.append( ";type=i" );

            BufferedInputStream bis = null;
            BufferedOutputStream bos = null;
            try
            {
                URL url = new URL( sb.toString() );
                URLConnection urlc = url.openConnection();

                log("urlc::1 "+urlc);

                bos = new BufferedOutputStream( urlc.getOutputStream() );
                log("bos:: "+bos);

                bis = new BufferedInputStream( is );

                int i;
                // read byte by byte until end of stream
                while ((i = bis.read()) != -1)
                {
                    log("i"+i);
                    bos.write( i );
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                if (bis != null)
                    try
                {
                        bis.close();
                }
                catch (IOException ioe)
                {
                    ioe.printStackTrace();
                }
                if (bos != null)
                    try
                {
                        bos.close();
                }
                catch (IOException ioe)
                {
                    ioe.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            log( "Input not available." );
        }
            }
```

For more details I am using java.net imports.

I am getting error :

```
Exception e is :: java.io.IOException: illegal filename for a PUT
    at sun.net.www.protocol.ftp.FtpURLConnection.getOutputStream(Unknown Source)
    at ToolFileUpload.upload(ToolFileUpload.java:72)
    at APInterfaceTool.uploadFile(APInterfaceTool.java:861)
    at APInterfaceTool.createInvoiceTextFile(APInterfaceTool.java:613)
    at APInterfaceTool.generateOutBoundExtract(APInterfaceTool.java:426)
```

Comment: `java.io.IOException: illegal filename for a PUT`
occurs whenever your file is either `null` or length of its name is `0`. Debug on these lines.

Comment: I found that problem is with the FTP Server. I tried the same code at other FTP Server and it works fine. Thank you everyone for your help

Answer (score 0):

The code in `FtpURLConnection.getOutputStream` that throws the exception is:

```
decodePath(url.getPath());
if (filename == null || filename.length() == 0) {
    throw new IOException("illegal filename for a PUT");
}
```

As you can see, the problem is that the `filename` component that has been parsed out of the URL is empty or missing.

The most likely cause is that you are supplying inappropriate parameters to the `upload` method.  Unfortunately, you haven't included the code that calls that method, so I can't go any further.

Comment: I checked from the logs neither the file name is null nor the file length is zero. Also I have put the whole method above. It is method named upload.

Comment: I am trying this stand alone program to upload file to FTP Server. Code runs fine but file is not created on the FTP

Comment: Thanks you very much for your support. I found that problem is with FTP Server as the same code runs fine on other FTP Server. :D

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the parameter you are passing, `FileInputStream is`, is not null when you call the function?

Comment: Yes, I checked it is not null. what could be the problem ?

Comment: It must be that the code tries to create a file that already exists. I guess [this](http://www.coderanch.com/t/277808/Streams/java/Copy-file-window-machine-Linux) might help.

Comment: I found that problem is with the FTP Server. I tried the same code at other FTP Server and it works fine. Thank you everyone for your help.